# TLS with TURN server

Tags: sockets, ssl, stun

I'm using TURN server and I want to use TLS when authenticating with TURN server but turn it off when it starts acting as relay server. how is this possible? it gives "connection reset" error as soon as I start transmitting unencrypted text
Thanks

Comment: Great question for the [RFC-5766-TURN-SERVER mailing list](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server). Ask for Oleg. Tell him I sent you.

Comment: Also, doesn't OpenSSL support the idea of renegotiating the encryption after the connection is made? You could simply renegotiate for the "null cipher" after you do the TURN ALLOCATE.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: no, its not possible they said.